# Error when running external php mysql query through JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hey so I am using JQuery to call a file '`login.php`'. When I click log in on the pop up modal I get the error

```
Access denied for user 'urbanas8'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

When I know the connection to the database is correct and it works with other pages that do not call external PHP files. I don't understand why this error is occurring but maybe one of you guys can tell me whats going on here?

Login Modal

```
<!--LOGIN MODAL -->
<?php require_once( "./inc/connect.inc.php" ); ?>
<div class="modal fade col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4" id="login" role="dialogue">
    <div class="modal-dialogue">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body row">    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" placeholder="email address">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userPassword" placeholder="password">
                    </div>
                    <!-- END ADDRESS FORM -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class = "btn btn-warning" id="loginButton" value="login" name="/login">Login</button><a class = "btn btn-warning" data-dismiss = "modal">Cancel</a>
            </div>
                </form>
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#loginButton").click(function(){
                        console.log("test123");
                        var username = $("#userName").val();
                        var password = $("#userPassword").val();
                        $.post("../login.php", {login:username, password:password}, function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`login.php`

```
<?php   

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    echo "<br>login is set<br>";
    $user_login = strip_tags($_POST['login']);  
    echo $user_login."<br>";
    $password_login = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    echo $password_login."<br>";
    $password_login = md5($password_login);
    echo $password_login."<br>";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$user_login' AND password='$password_login' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
    $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    echo $userCount."<br>";
    if($userCount == 1){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

            $user_id = $row["id"];
            $user_fname = $row["first_name"];
            $user_lname = $row["last_name"];
            $user_membersince = $row["date"];

        }

        $_SESSION['user_email'] = $user_login;
        $_SESSION['user_fname'] = $user_fname;
        $_SESSION['user_lname'] = $user_lname;
        $_SESSION['user_membersince'] = $user_membersince;

        echo("logged in!");

    }else {
        echo("invalid username/password");
    }
}
?>
```

`connection.inc.php`

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "urbanas8_login", "Ure1982*") or die(mysql_error);
mysql_select_db('urbanas8_db', $db) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: There is no connection defined on `login.php`

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in your username through which your are logging into mysql. Your error message shows username 'urbanas8' but your connection file shows 'urbanas8_login'.

you have not included the file "connection.inc.php" in login.php

I recommend you to use mysqli instead of mysql. it is deprecated.

```
<?php 
//conection: 
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 

//consultation: 

$query = "SELECT name FROM mytable" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); 

//execute the query. 

$result = $link->query($query); 

//display information: 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
  echo $row["name"] . "<br>"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: I'm already connected through connection.inc.php. I added the code to the top of my login.php and got the same result.

Comment: how do I do that? I'll post my connection file

Comment: thats the login name the connection.php works fine on every other page

Comment: your error message is showing different username then your connection file, see @MichaelCollins

Comment: why do you think that is?

Comment: without correct username how would you login to mysql server. Thats why it is showing Access denied error @MichaelCollins

Comment: I'm looking at mysql databases right now that's the proper user name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82156/discussion-between-hitesh-mundra-and-michael-collins).